# Webkit won't produce a click

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webkit, click

I been up all night trying to invoke a click, I have read many posts on this site, webkits site, and google. When using just the plain webbrowser1 the previous code worked. That's right here:

```
        HtmlElementCollection elems = Web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
        {
            String value = elem.GetAttribute("value");
            if (elem.InnerText == "Done!")
            {
                elem.InvokeMember("click");
            }

        }
```

But with webkit it does not, the code had to be switched to:

```
        WebKit.DOM.NodeList elems = Web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a‌​");
        foreach (WebKit.DOM.Element ele in elems)
        {
            String value = ele.GetAttribute("value");
            if (ele.TextContent == "Done!")
            {
               //Need to find a way to invoke a click with webkit
            }
        }
```

I wanna invoke a click for this, but everything I try comes up with an error stating:

```
'WebKit.DOM.NodeList' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeMember' and no extension method 'InvokeMember' accepting a first argument of type 'WebKit.DOM.NodeList'
```

Could someone please help me with this issue, I don't wanna go back to using the default web browser, Java doesn't function correctly and every time the button is clicked it refreshes the page, sometimes causing the page not to load. With webkit everything on the page works flawless.

Comment: what language is this anyway?